# When to use the OpenCL API scalar data types?

Tags: c, types, opencl

I have been having trouble understanding when to use the OpenCL API data types like cl_float, cl_uchar, etc., which can be found here:

http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/scalarDataTypes.html

The examples I have seen that involve copying a buffer to the device look like this:

```
float data[DATA_SIZE];              // original data set given to device

//Create the input and output arrays in device memory for our calculation
input = clCreateBuffer(context,  CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,  sizeof(float) * count, NULL,

// Write our data set into the input array in device memory
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commands, input, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * count, data, 0, NULL, NULL);
if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Error: Failed to write to source array!\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

This code was taken directly from an Apple code sample available here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/OpenCL_Hello_World_Example/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

You will notice in the above code that an array of floats is copied to the device. Why does this not need to be an array of cl_floats? The memory is directly copied, right? What happens if your host float and the device float are not the same size?

Could you explain why it is not necessary to use cl_float? If it is not necessary in this case, then when *should* the opencl types be used?

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of these `cl_`-prefixed types are they are defined as the same size on the host and device by the OpenCL runtime. In practice, for simple types such as a `float` you can often get away without using `cl_float` (as a `float` and `cl_float` are often the same size) but it is always recommended to use the `cl_`-prefixed types for maximum portability. As pointed out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398480/when-to-use-the-opencl-api-scalar-data-types/25398700?noredirect=1#comment39616918_25398700) (thanks @DarkZeros), a good example of a type that may cause problems is an `int`, as this can vary in size depending on the host platform. Using `cl_int` means that this is not a problem.

As pointed out in the documentation that you have linked to, OpenCL C is based on C99 with *specific extensions and restrictions* (I've heard it described as a "supersubset" :-). As well as ensuring that the sizes of your types match up, you are also limiting yourself to using types that are defined in OpenCL C (`size_t` doesn't have a matching `cl_size_t`, for example).

In terms of your example, the buffers are the same size as the reads and writes that are being carried out but the potential problem is that the device may have a differently sized `float` type, so your kernels may potentially be working with garbage values. I would change all instances of `float` to `cl_float` to guard against this possibility.

Comment: So to be safe, every time we want to send an array of host_type from somewhere else in our program to the device we need to copy and cast it to a new array of cl_type? And do the opposite for the data we read back?

Comment: If there is no good reason to work with native C types in your host code, instead of casting I would suggest working with the `cl_` types directly. I've added an additional paragraph to my answer by the way.

Comment: I see. In my case and I imagine most other cases, the inputs and results of an opencl computation must be provided/consumed by the rest of the host program. You might also like to keep opencl dependencies out of the rest of your code. That amounts to an unfortunate number of copies and boilerplate conversions. But I guess it can't be helped!

Comment: One good example is `cl_int`. In OpenCL is 32bits ALWAYS. While each C platform may have different int size.