# what's the difference between int and cl_int in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

There are many data types in OpenCL, such as `int`, `cl_int`, `char`, `cl_char`, 'short', 'cl_short'. But what is the difference between `int` and `cl_int`, and when should I use `cl_int` instead of `int`?

Comment: [This](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/scalarDataTypes.html) wasn't of any help?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist actually I have read that page, but I still don't know when to use `cl_int` and when to use `int`. so I want to know if there exists conventions or best practices.

Comment: Could be considered as a duplicate: Maybe you'll find the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25398700/3182664 helpful

Comment: @Marco13 that question solves my problem. when I search google and stackoveflow, I didn't find that question. thx....

Answer (score 8):

The size of an `int` in C/C++ is machine dependent. It is guaranteed to be *at least* 16 bits, but these days will usually be 32 bits, and could also be 64. This poses a problem when passing data between a host and device in OpenCL - if the device has a different idea about what the size of an `int` is, then passing an `int` value(s) to the device might not produce the expected result.

The OpenCL headers provide the `cl_int` definition to provide a datatype that is *always* 32 bits, which matches the size that an OpenCL device expects. This means that you can pass a `cl_int` value, or an array of `cl_int` values from the host to device (and back), without running into problems with the sizes being mismatched.

So, whenever you are writing host code that deals with values or buffers that will be passed to the device, you should always use the `cl_` datatypes.